# Filter out all users created 23 days ago using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a user expiring notification module. In that module I want to send emails when users completed 23 days from their 30 days trial period.And after the 30 days trial period completed I wanna send them the trial period expired email. To do that task I wanna make a efficient mysql queries for both tasks.

example : created_time = 2018-08-08 23:16:55

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: MySQL isn't really the tool for sending email, you'd want to do that from PHP.  But this means you are asking for a query, some PHP code, and maybe other things.

Comment: yes friend I just want to check the all users when they exceed their 23 days period . I want a mysql query to filler out them

Comment: Then please tell us what you have researched & what you have tried so far. Just “wanting” something really isn’t enough here on SO, you need to make _some_ effort. If you don’t know how to even start to research this, then type something like “mysql select records from x days ago” or similar into Google, you will find lots of similar questions.

Comment: SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE created_time >= DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 23 DAY); I tried this one so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get every user between 30 and 23 days, use

```
select * from users 
where (created_time not between DateAdd(DD,-23,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()) 
AND (created_time between DateAdd(DD,-30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE())
```

Comment: hello what is "DateAdd" ? Thank you

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp

Comment: You gotta start googling...

Comment: DATEADD is for [sql-server] not for [mysql]

Comment: @anon are you sure it is not usable? Sry then.

Comment: public static function getNotifyUser($expireTime){
  $db = new DBManager();
  $select = $db->select();
  $select ->from('user')
    ->columns(['email']);
  $where = new Where();
  $where = lessThan('created_time',$expireTime);
  $select->where($where)->limit(1);
  $resultSet = $db->zendSelect($select);
  
  // echo $db->getSqlstringForSqlObject($select);
  // exit;
 
  return $resultSet;
 }

Comment: I'm using zend framework . This query not working because of Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Classes\lessThan() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/polysmart/vendor/custom/Classes/User.php:308 error . but i have added use Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2) function in mysql can be used to get date user remaining days.

```
select datediff('2018-09-06', '2018-08-19') as expiredate
```

expr1 has to be current date.

based on expiredate value write a php function to send mail.

DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2) returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation

Comment: public function notifyAction(){
  $expireTime = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-23 days"));

  $respose = User::getNotifyUser($expireTime);
  print_r($respose);
 }

Comment: public static function getNotifyUser($expireTime){
  $db = new DBManager();
  $select = $db->select();
  $select ->from('user')
    ->columns(['email']);
  $where = new Where();
  $where = lessThan('created_time',$expireTime);
  $select->where($where)->limit(1);
  $resultSet = $db->zendSelect($select);
  
  // echo $db->getSqlstringForSqlObject($select);
  // exit;
 
  return $resultSet;
 }
I'm working in zend framework . this query is wrong . please help me to fix this query